# What is the cause of websocket latency spikes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, tornado

I am running a server (that uses tornado python) on a single AWS instance and I am running into spikes in websocket latency.

Profiling the round trip time from when a websocket message is sent to the client, which then immediately sends an ack message back to the server, to when the server receives the ack message yields an average of <.1 second, however I note sometimes it goes up to 3 seconds. Note: there are no spikes when running the server locally.

What could be the cause or fix for this? I looked at the CPU usage and it only goes up to 40% max. The spikes are not correlated with heavy traffic (2 or 3 clients usually) and the client's internet seems fine. I find it hard to believe the instance is going beyond capacity with such low usage.

Answer (score 7):

The fact that the spike is 3 seconds is actually telling you a lot more than you may suspect, about the nature of the problem.

It's packet loss.

TCP, as you likely know, is said to provide "reliable" transport, guaranteeing that payload sent is received by the far end in the order in which it was sent, because TCP reassembles things in the correct order before delivering the payload.  One significant way in which this is accomplished is by the automatic retransmission of packets that are considered to have been lost.

You'll never guess the default initial timer value for retransmissions of lost packets.  Or, perhaps, now, you will.

It's 3 seconds in many, if not most, implementations, based on standards established several years ago in a time when the bandwidth and latency of today's transmission links were unheard of, perhaps unimagined.

You won't see evidence of the retransmission at at the websocket server or the client software, because TCP shields the higher layers from knowing that it occurs... but 3 seconds is a dead giveaway that this is exactly the problem.

You'll see the retransmissions of the traffic occurring if you observe the network traffic with a packet sniffer, though that will only serve to confirm that this is the issue.

It could be loss from server to client, or loss from client to server.  The latter is generally more likely, since clients often have a lower amount of available upstream bandwidth... but the directionality of the packet loss doesn't clearly indicate the physical location where it is occurring.  Unless your client keeps track of local time, so that request and response initiation times can be correlated, you don't know whether the delay is in the message, or in the acknowledgement.

Under relatively light load, it seems unlikely that the problem is on your instance or in the AWS network on your side, and you obviously can't connect a sniffer to arbitrary points on the Internet to pinpoint the problem.

Given a case like this, it may be easier -- and surprisingly feasible -- to prove where the problem *isn't*, rather than where it *is*.

One technique for this would be to create a deliberate detour for the traffic through different equipment located elsewhere -- such as a different AWS region or another cloud provider.

First, of course, you'll want to learn to spot these retransmissions using wireshark.

Then, configure a proxy server at a different location, using a simple TCP connection proxy -- such as HAProxy, or even a simple tool like `redir` or `socat`.

Such a configuration will listen for connections from clients, and when one is established, will create a new TCP connection to the destination (your websocket server) but -- importantly -- they only tie the two connections together at the payload level -- not the TCP level, and of course nothing lower -- so retransmissions will only be seen on the wire at all between this intermediate server and the end of the connection with the packet loss problem.  The other end will show no evidence of the retransmissions -- just data arriving later than expected.

For this test to be meaningful, the proxy needs to be located away from the server and the client, and with no meaningful common infrastructure -- hence the suggestion of placing it in a different AWS region.  A different availability zone in the same region may share common Internet infrastructure at some level, so that's not far enough away for this purpose.

If `client <--> proxy <--> server` shows TCP retransmissions on the path between proxy and server, and not between client and proxy, the problem really is likely to be in your server, its hardware, network, or Internet connection, and you'll have to proceed accordingly.

Conversely (and, I would suggest, more likely) if the path between proxy and server is free of retransmissions but the path between client and proxy is still dirty, you have eliminated the server and its infrastructure as the source of the problem.  How to proceed is up to you, but at this point you do know what the problem... isn't.

Two other possibilities:

Both sides remain dirty, which is the least likely scenario.  Rule 1 of troubleshooting is to assume initially that you only have one problem, not two.

Or, both sides are suddenly and unexectedly clean when traffic uses this setup, which suggests thay your test setup has routed around a broken piece of the Internet.  You've "solved" it but have no idea how.  We'll also hope this isn't the outcome, but given the vagaries of the global Internet, it's not unthinkable that your stack may include components like this, with geolocation-DNS-based selection of an intermediate endpoint.  This seems like a convolution but does have its place.

Such a tactic is actually part of the logic behind the [S3 transfer acceleration](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-storage-update-amazon-s3-transfer-acceleration-larger-snowballs-in-more-regions/) feature.  The content is not any closer to the end user, but the TCP connection from the browser is being terminated on equipment in the AWS edge network, at a location that is often nearer to the browser, and a second TCP connection back to the bucket is established, with the payload connected together... and, yes, it's faster and more stable, with the significance of the change becoming more notable as distance and connection quality vary.

Comment: I attempted to verify packet loss by using wireshark to observe traffic but I haven't been able to confirm it. I can observe packet loss frames in when I do not have any delays from the client and although I haven't been able to consistently reproduce the lag, I haven't been able to find any lag that correlated with a dropped packet frame. I also was curious how other websockets servers handle packet loss since they seem to scale to much more users still remain responsive.

Comment: You don't want to confuse two issues, here.  Packet loss can certainly accompany increased traffic but there is currently no reason to believe the issue you are experiencing is related to the load on your server nor that it would necessarily be worse at scale.  Can you extend your code so that the client sends time from its local clock?  Once you establish the offset, it would be interesting to know the directionality of the error, and  it seems like you'd need a client timestamp for that.  If you'd like to try a man-in-the-middle test, check my SO profile for contact info.

Comment: I have issues sending the timestamp from the client since it will send their local machine's time which I can't account for when comparing to a server timestamp

Comment: Yes, you can... as long as you calculate and remember the offset between the two.  If my clock appears to be 5 minutes ahead of yours, then 5 minutes, then 5 minutes, then suddenly 4 minutes 57 seconds, then you know the latency is **from me to you** because I must have looked at my clock 3 seconds before you "heard" me tell you the "current" time.  If, from your perspective, my clock's offset never changes, even if you sometimes see a delayed response, then the latency is **from you to me**, because I don't look at my clock until I hear you ask me to, and you receive my answer immediately.

Comment: I ran a profile and calculated time the msg was received on a client minus the time a msg was sent from the server and recorded times mostly less than 1 second up to over 3 seconds. This causes me to believe the latency is coming from the server (otherwise the delays server -> client should be ~constant and the rtt spikes would be client -> server). How would one approach fixing the server if my belief is correct?